# C#: Interface implementation

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I found the following implementation in a code base I am going through

```
Interface IOrder
{
GetSubmittedOrder();
CreateOrder();
GetExistingOrder();
}

Class Order : IOrder
{
BuildSpecialOrder();
AddSpecialOrderParameters();
IOrder.GetSubmittedOrder();
IOrder.CreateOrder();
IOrder.GetExistingOrder();
}
```

Now, when we want to access the last three methods from this `Order` object, we need to do the following declaration

```
IOrder objOrder = new Order();
```

What is the reason(advantages) for creating an implementation like this? Does this practice have a specific name?

*Note: Please let me know if this is a better fit at programmers.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that that's the incorrect usage of *[explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx)*. It basically means that the methods are not visible in the public class contract. That's why you have to cast the object to the interface type first (you are using an implicit cast). You could also have done:

```
var order = (IOrder)order;
order.GetExistingOrder();
```

It's normally used when the class method collides with an interface method or when a class implements two interfaces with the same method  (but different purposes).

It should be used with care since it can indicate that your class have a too large responsibility (and should be divided into smaller classes).

Comment: A third use scenario is when you need to implement the interface, but you don't want to support one of the methods in that interface. For example, `System.Array` implements `ICollection`, but the `Add` method throws an `NotSupportedException` because arrays are fixed-sized. It is therefore natural to not implement `Add` with an ordinary `public` method (since it's a method that always throws).

Comment: Thanks for the succicint answer! Are you telling me that the way(syntax) I have invoked the function is wrong, or that the fact that I am able to access these function through the object is wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong. It's just not how you typically use explicit interface implementation. To me it looks like the developer making the class is unsure of if the class should implement that interface or not (since he hides the methods)

Comment: Or simply when you don't want interface methods polluting the public face of the hosting class.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: That's a violation of the Liskovs Substitution Principle (but still probably the best way to do it if you ***really*** have to).

Comment: @dthorpe: Addressed by my last paragraph

Comment: @jgauffin Sure it violates Liskov! But the BCL uses it. (But it is from `IList`, not `ICollection`.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It's not proper usage just because Microsoft did it. Avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 3):

Its called [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

It is used to differentiate the implementation of specific interface in case multiple interface are implemented have the colliding names of methods.

```
interface IOrder
{
  GetSubmittedOrder();
  CreateOrder();
  GetExistingOrder();
}

interface ISpecificOrder
{
  GetSubmittedOrder();
  CreateOrder();
  GetExistingOrder();
}

Class Order : IOrder, ISpecificOrder
{
  BuildSpecialOrder();
  AddSpecialOrderParameters();

  IOrder.GetSubmittedOrder();
  IOrder.CreateOrder();
  IOrder.GetExistingOrder();

  ISpecificOrder.GetSubmittedOrder();
  ISpecificOrder.CreateOrder();
  ISpecificOrder.GetExistingOrder();

}
```

Comment: Incorrect. The same class method can be used to implement all interface methods with the same name. That's the default behavior.

Comment: @jgauffin Yes you are right. One should choose explicit interface implementation in case you want different behavior for different interfaces.

Comment: @asif: don't you mean explicit?

Answer (score 1):

Consider adapter pattern [Wiki - Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)
When communicating with other application or part of app (and many other requirements), you dont want to bind the type as it will be decided on run time, you can use this type of object declaration. this will create the object of interface type but will allocate memory of required type(nested in switch case or returned by other function).

```
 IOrder objOrder = new Order();
```

Another thing mentioned in question is about implicit and explicit implementation of interface. Both can be used in different scenario. You can find more details from google.